# Pass function and also argument to a function

Tags: javascript

Can I pass function and parameters to function as arguments?

I can pass only function and it is working

```
function wrap(foo) { 
 foo();
};

wrap(() => {
 console.log("test")
});
```

But I want to also pass some parameters to function **wrap**. Not only function **foo**

Comment: Yes you can. Show what you've tried because it is possible.

Comment: try like this .    function wrap(foo,onemore) { 
 foo();     console.log(onemore);
};

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can

```js
function wrap(foo, bar) {
  console.log(bar);
  foo();
};

wrap(() => {
  console.log("test")
}, 'somebar value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can pass extra parameter in function

```
function wrap(foo, msgObj) { 
 foo(msgObj.msg);
};

wrap((msg) => {
 console.log("test", msg)
// test, here is your extra value
},
 {msg:'here is your extra value'}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do that:**

```js
function wrap(foo, externalMsg) { 
 foo(externalMsg);
};

wrap((msg) => {
 console.log(msg)
}, 'Ele from SO');
```

**Even, you can initialize params with a predefined function:**

```js
function wrap(externalMsg, foo = (msg) => {
 console.log(msg)
}) { 
 foo(externalMsg);
};

wrap('Ele from SO');
```